# Highcharts draggable points with polar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to get [draggable-points](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dragDrop) to work with polar charts.

Here is my [JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m9ywno1j/).

If you change the chart.polar setting to false, you will get a line chart where drag&drop works.

```
chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'area'
}
```

I found an older fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wrzm5/) where someone implemented it manually with mouse listeners, but recently drag&drop seems to be supported natively which I'd prefer.

Comment: If you take a look on the [unminified version of the draggble module](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/draggable-points.src.js) you will find `if (chart.hasCartesianSeries && !chart.polar) {` (search for 'polar'). So I don't think that's possible without a manual implementation.

Comment: Hi @fancy, As @Core972 rightly noticed, the draggable-points module is not supported by default with `polar` chart type.

Comment: Thank you. I used d3 now instead to get it to work. (https://d3js.org)